# object not saving on heroku, but is locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

A User has_many Positions. This is part of an Auth controller that calls LinkedIn for the User to authenticate:

```
positions.each do |position|

    @li_pos_id = position.id
    @title = position.title
    @company = position.company.name
    @industry = position.company.industry
    @start_month = position.start_date.month
    @start_year = position.start_date.year
    @end_month = position.end_date.month
    @end_year = position.end_date.year

    current_user.positions.build(li_pos_id: @li_pos_id, title: @title, company: @company, industry: @industry, 
      start_month: @start_month, start_year: @start_year, end_month: @end_month, end_year: @end_year)
end
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why current_user.positions.build(...) creates a Position in my development (Postgres) database but not on Heroku (also Postgres). My User object is creating just fine upon authentication. From my sessions controller:

```
def create
      user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to auth_path
    end
```

which calls the following from my user model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice('provider', 'uid')).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
    end

    def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
      create! do |user|
        user.provider = auth['provider']
        user.uid = auth['uid']
      end
    end
```

My user model contains the necessary 'has_many :positions', and my position model has 'belongs_to :user'. Regardless, the current_user.positions.build(...) line creates the appropriate positions in development but simply doesn't in production.

Would really appreciate any help here! Thank you.

Comment: `build` doesn't save the records, it just builds them.  Are you saving the current user somewhere after the positions are built in the first part?

Comment: When you say it works locally, are you using SQLite as your local database? Or PostgreSQL? If you're using SQLite locally, it could be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063993/rails-app-on-heroku-cannot-write-to-postgresql-database-only-read

Comment: using postgresql in dev and prod, so sqlite should not be the issue. I was attempting to save them by setting the build to a positions instance variable and finishing up the auth controller's position.each loop with @positions.save, but still no luck!